# python how to make this code more pythonic?

Tags: python

So I got this code from lecture18 of "Introduction to computers science and programming" lectures from MIT. The codes rarely follows the pythonic style. Check this out

```
class Item(object):

def __init__(self, n, v, w):
    self.name = n
    self.value = float(v)
    self.weight = float(w)

def getName(self):
    return self.name

def getValue(self):
    return self.value

def getWeight(self):
    return self.weight

def __str__(self):
    result = '<' + self.name + ', ' + str(self.value) + ', '\
             + str(self.weight) + '>'
    return result



def buildItems():
    names = ['clock', 'painting', 'radio', 'vase', 'book',
             'computer']
    vals = [175,90,20,50,10,200]
    weights = [10,9,4,2,1,20]
    Items = []
    #for i in range(len(vals)):
    #    Items.append(Item(names[i], vals[i], weights[i]))

    return Items
```

How to change the commented code of the function to a pythonic code?

This is how I did it:

```
for tup in zip(names, vals, weights):
            name, value, weight = tup
            Items.append(Item(name, value, weight))
```

Any other way?

EDIT: [Lec 18 | MIT 6.00SC Introduction to Computer Science and Programming, Spring 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRjwkgQct28&list=PLB2BE3D6CA77BB8F7&index=26)

Comment: If the code works, this probably belongs to CodeReview.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about code review.

Comment: Where did you get that code? Add a link or fix your reference (add year) as Lecuture 18 in MIT's **Intro to computer science...** did not include code like that

Comment: The question as it stands would not fare well on Code Review. The title and body of the question have no explanation of what the code does, or whether it works correctly or not. If the code works and the question is reworded with that in mind, then it would do fine on Code Review.

Answer (score 6):

```
Items = list(map(Item,zip(names,vals,weights)))
```

maybe?

or

```
Items = [Item(*vals) for vals in zip(names,vals,weights)]
```

[edit] Unfortunately after consideration the first example will not work since it passes all 3 arguments as one tuple without unpacking ... you would likely have to change the init function of Item to accept a tuple or use a lambda

```
Items = list(map(lambda a:Item(*a),zip(names,vals,weights)))
```

Comment: Actually the alternatively works. Plus one :)

Comment: I love the first one. Thank you

Comment: hmmm actually i dont think the first one will actually work ... since it doesnt unpack the arguments ... dang sorry ...

Answer (score 4):

This is even shorter:

```
Items = [Item(name,value,weight) for name,value,weight in zip(names,vals,weights)]
```

Comment: Oh that's beautiful.